Docker compose up doesn't recreate new container with changed image
So, imagine i have a docker compose of 5 services and one of them is a container that runs some code in any programming language(c# in my case). I'm changing the code and doing the docker compose up --build -d command. As for my understanding, it should build new images if some of them were changed(i changed my code) and replace containers that were using old images with new that are using new images. Here, container replacement doesn't work.
After using docker compose up --build -d command i either have to manually restart container(somehow it starts using new image now) or use the --force-recreate option that's not very acceptable in my case since other images didn't change and i dont want to restart their containers.
My IDE shows that by default docker compose up replaces container if images or configurations changed, but it doesn't.
Docker and compose versions
>docker --version
Docker version 27.2.0, build 3ab4256

>docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.29.2-desktop.2

Simple usecase
Web application(so it keeps container running) and some output lines
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
app.Run()


I docker-compose-uping it using this command


C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe compose -f
C:\Users\Alexei\RiderProjects\ConsoleApp3\docker-compose.yml -p
consoleapp3 up -d --build

and get this in the console:

10/06/2024 21:41:31
Hello, World!


After this, i delete the line with "Hello, World!" output and using the same compose again. Logs are the same! Hello, world didn't disappear.
If i restart container, its logs don't include "Hello world"

I think it means compose-up didn't replace older container during it's work.
P.S.
It seems the problem is in docker compose up command generated by IDE. i mentioned it above. with usual docker compose up --build -d works fine, replacing working container

According to the documentation there is --watch / -w flag that does what you need:

Watch source code and rebuild/refresh containers when files are updated.

Try to use it like this docker compose up --build -d --watch

This is not what i need. My problem is not hot-reloading but container replacement after building new image
